# Kioskmode with Powershell - Can't start App 0xffffffff

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode

I would like to set Edge as an Assigned Access to a User.
I'm using the following PowerShell Command:

```
Net localgroup administrators /add

Net localgroup administratoren administrators /add

$user = "KioskUser"
$userDesc = "Kiosk account with assigned Access"
New-LocalUser -Name $user -NoPassword -AccountNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -Description $userDesc | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Benutzer" -Member "$user"

Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge -UserName $user
```

The Skript works, but if i want to log in as KioskUser i always get the following error (translated from German):

"Your app could not be launched. Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE to log out or contact your system administrator. Search online for the error code 0xffffffff to get more Information."

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Im Using PS version 5.1.19041.1682

Comment: Which line causes the error? I tried your code and it worked on my system.

Comment: Did yo ustart PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin?

Comment: @Max The Skript works in Powershell, but if i log in with the KioskUser i get the Error.

Comment: @jdweng Yes i did. Maybe i need to make it clearer, The Skript works untill i want to log in with the user

Comment: Your system may not allow accounts with no password and never expire.

Comment: @spoon2 Alright, in that case the issue is that **Kiosk Mode only supports UWP apps** and MS Edge legacy has been update to MS Edge Chromium in some update a while ago so Kiosk with Edge is a big no-can-do

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge` is `AppUserModelId` for Legacy Edge. The `AppUserModelId` for Edge Chromium is `MSEdge`.
[image]

So the PowerShell script sets Legacy Edge to kiosk mode but now we use Edge Chromium, that's why you can't login.

It's true that we can't [use PowerShell to set up kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app#set-up-a-kiosk-using-windows-powershell) for Edge Chromium as it's not a UWP app. For configuring Edge Chromium kiosk mode, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode). After following the steps in the doc, then you can login Edge kiosk mode successfully.

Comment: Yess, thank you very much. But this doc only shows it with a GUI and i need to do it with Powershell.  But it seems like its harder than i expected because of the Edge Chromium

Comment: @spoon2 Seems we can't use PowerShell to set up Edge kiosk mode as PowerShell method only works for UWP apps.